# Why can't debug my Flutter App on my phone in VS Code while coding

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-sdk-manager

I've just setup my windows environment for mobile development using Flutter in VS Code but I am getting this error while trying to debug on my phone

avdmanager is missing from the Android SDK

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an emulator, check `AVD manager` is installed, and the emulator is installed. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-android-virtual-deviceavd/) is how to do that

or if you're using a physical phone
Here is one of the workaround:

Open Android Studio then click on SDK Manager (down-pointing arrow)

This should open a new box with your Android SDK Location at the top. It should look like this:

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
```

**Configure the path of android-sdk**

```
flutter config --android-sdk /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
```

**Add android-license to Flutter**

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Then, you can run `flutter doctor` to verify,

Comment: I am not using Android Studio for my configurations I did all without it